# Modify visual studio gives .net error

Tags: visual-studio, .net-framework, setup, installer

So I open visual studio installer, click modify on "Visual Studio Professional 2017 ver 15.7.3" and then receive the issue "The dependent package of 'Microsoft.Net.PackageGroup.4.6.Redist, version=15.0.27005.2' cannot be found: Microsoft.Net.4.6.FullRedist.NonThreshold,version=4.6.0.0."

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jP6a.png

Same error occurs if I try to uninstall VS 2017.

My initial thought was to simply reinstall .Net 4.6, but I have yet to be able to find any way to do so.

I have tried restarting, uninstalling the installer and reinstalling it. Restarting again, at this point I am at a loss of what more to try.

Edit:

When trying to perform install of .NET Framework 4.6 I get ".NET Framework 4.6 or later update is already installed on this computer" (Same thing occurs no matter which version I try to install) - https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQkJD.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ar1kA.png

Os ver: Win 10 build 17134

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: In order to answer this question I need to know what version of Windows you are using.  If it’s Windows 10 include the build number.

Comment: Win 10 build 17134

Comment: If you have 1803 then your machine has 4.7.2, which means, you can’t install 4.6.  As for the error I would attempt to download the VS2017 installer again.

Comment: I have already downloaded and tried to reinstall the installer, no change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got a response from the MS support team, the issue was due to a file managing the installations got corrupt.

The solution to this was:

Please follow the cleanup steps and retry your VS install

- See if you have this file on your machine:
  "%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual
  Studio\Installer\resources\app\layout\InstallCleanup.exe"
- If so, please launch it from an admin command prompt with a -full
  param:

InstallCleanup.exe -full

- If not, please manually delete the "%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft
  Visual Studio\Installer” folder
- Relaunch the newly downloaded vs_enterprise.exe (or
  vs_professional.exe or vs_community.exe…)
- Allow the first step to install the installer
- Once the installer comes up and you can see workload choices (.net
  desktop and the like), close it
- Go launch the same InstallCleanup.exe to clean up old build of VS
- Then relaunch vs_enterprise.exe and install VS

Comment: -1. Lost the programme after using the installCleaup.exe -full. And launching the installer doesn't work anymore. The programme is still listed under softwares, cannot remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this page: [Microsoft .NET downloads](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/guide-for-developers)

You should be able to download the proper version of .NET there.

Comment: I have added an edit in the first post, when I try to do an install I get an error due to "4.6 or a later update already installed"

Comment: do you have the correct developer pack installed? Go to this page: [Developer Packs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3186612/the-net-framework-4-7-developer-pack-and-language-packs)

Comment: I do yes, https://i.imgur.com/5pPvEk3.png  (removed previous comment as I couldnt edit it)